# How to find the mean number of day each combination of user ids and week number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of users activity that looks like this:

| ID | week | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23/07/22 |
| 1 | 1 | 24/07/22 |
| 1 | 2 | 29/07/22 |
| 1 | 2 | 30/07/22 |
| 1 | 2 | 01/08/22 |
| 2 | 1 | 22/07/22 |
| 2 | 2 | 29/07/22 |
| 2 | 2 | 02/08/22 |

In week 1, there are 3 days: 22/07/22 (day 1), 23/07/22 (day 2), 24/07/22 (day 3)

In week 2, there are 4 days: 29/07/22 (day 1), 30/07/22 (day 2), 01/08/22 (day 3), 02/08/22 (day 4)

I need the average of days numbers as a new column: user with ID 1 visited the site on days 2 and 3 of week 1, so the average is 2.5.

The output I need is:

| ID | week | mean_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.5 |

I hope my question is clear, I don't know how to start and will appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: "and I need 2 new columns- the average of days (if a user visited the site on days 1,2,3 so the output will be 2), and also a column called day 1 where the value will be 1 if user entered on day 1 of that week, and 0 if he didn't." - These are two separate questions.

Comment: for the first row- user ID 1 visited on dates 23/07/22/ & 24/07/22, which are day number 2 & 3, so the mean of 2 & 3 is 2.5. In week 1 there are 3 days as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "week": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
        "date": [
            "23/07/22",
            "24/07/22",
            "29/07/22",
            "30/07/22",
            "01/08/22",
            "22/07/22",
            "29/07/22",
            "02/08/22",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) methods:

```py
# Prep data
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(["week", "date"]).reset_index(drop=True)

# Add day number to df as new column "day_num"
tmp = df.groupby("week").agg(set)
tmp["day_num"] = tmp.apply(lambda x: [i + 1 for i in range(len(x["date"]))], axis=1)
tmp["date"] = tmp["date"].apply(sorted)
tmp = tmp.explode(["date", "day_num"])
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('date'), tmp.set_index('date').drop(columns="ID")], axis=1)

# Evaluate mean as new column "mean_day"
df = (
    df.sort_values(["ID", "week"])
    .groupby(["ID", "week"])
    .agg(pd.DataFrame.mean)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"date": "mean_day"})
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   ID  week  day_num
0   1     1      2.5
1   1     2      2.0
2   2     1      1.0
3   2     2      2.5
```